# Is UWP / XAML C# compatible with the Spotify API?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, spotify, libspotify

I am learning development for Windows Universal Platform and I wanted to create a simple app capable of leveraging some Spotify data once the user logs in.

I can see from the documentation that there is an **SDK** for Android and **iOS**, and a library that is considered deprecated.

Do you guys know if there is any way for me to still communicate with the Spotify API using `.NET/C#` ?

Thanks a lot,

Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a SDK from Spotify, but there are references to WebApi .Net Wrappers at the bottom of [this official page](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/):

- [Spotify Web API Wrapper on Codeplex](https://spotifywebapi.codeplex.com/)
- [Spotify Web API Wrapper on GitHub](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET)

Comment: The Api uses Webclient - guess you will need to fix this to get it working with UWP - should be a a nice and pull request.

Comment: Ah cool, I am going to have a look and keep you posted once I start working on that part of the app. Thanks!